# How do I access the actor system used in Play 2.5 from within a Module

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I need access to the default actor system that Play Framework 2.5 uses from within my `Module` class.

I see that there is a method on `ActorSystemProvider` to get this:

```
@Singleton
class ActorSystemProvider @Inject()(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration, applicationLifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) extends Provider[ActorSystem] {
  private val logger = Logger(classOf[ActorSystemProvider])

  lazy val get: ActorSystem = {
    val (system, stopHook) = ActorSystemProvider.start(environment.classLoader, configuration)
    applicationLifecycle.addStopHook(stopHook)
    system
  }
}
```

But how do I get access to this class in my `Module` class?

For example:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule {
  val playSystem: ActorSytem = ???  
  ...
}
```

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I have a service object that needs a Map[String, ActorRef] and that would be built in the Module class, so I need the actor system to create the actors and build the map and I have actors that take functions in the contstructor/props method.  So I create classes that have methods that match the function signature but only pass in the function to the actor's props method.  This is all very easily done in the Module class but needs the actor system.

Comment: That would mean you'd have to start actors in your module, which is certainly not the idea. A module is basically a description of of your bindings in code (others do it in XML). this is not meant to contain such code. I would try to do it somehow else. Maybe some type of factory (or even `javax.inject.Provider`) that takes an `ActorSystem` and produces this `Map[String, ActorRef]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can access actorSystem by simply injecting it into any of the component constructor. You will get access to the actorSystem created by play and you need not do any of the provider gymnastics.

For example, I need actor system to be accessible in my HomeController. So, I just inject into my HomeController constructor.

```
class HomeController @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem) extends Controller {
  def index = Ok("bye!")
}
```